# Angular error TS2769: No overload matches this call. Overload 1 of 3

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angular13

I have the following problem when I try to get all data from realtime db in firebase:

When I remove `async` from the template, the error is gone but no data is retrieved! I don't understand what's the problem exactly!!

This is my code TS

```
tutos?:Tutorial[];
retrievetutos(): void {
    this.menuService.getAll().snapshotChanges().pipe(
      map(changes =>
        changes.map(c =>
          ({ key: c.payload.key, ...c.payload.val() })
        )
        
      )
    ).subscribe(data => {
      this.tutos = data;
    });
  }
```

HTML

```
<tr *ngFor="let tuto of tutos | async">
              <td>{{tuto.name}}</td>
              <td>{{tuto.price}}</td>
              
            </tr>
```

the Error  :

```
Error: src/app/components/dashboard/dashboard.component.html:49:37 - error TS2769: No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 3, '(obj: Observable<any[] | Iterable<any> | undefined> | Subscribable<any[] | Iterable<any> | undefined> | Promise<any[] | Iterable<any> | undefined>): any[] | ... 2 more ... | undefined', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'any[] | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Observable<any[] | Iterable<any> | undefined> | Subscribable<any[] | Iterable<any> | undefined> | Promise<any[] | Iterable<any> | undefined>'.
      Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'Observable<any[] | Iterable<any> | undefined> | Subscribable<any[] | Iterable<any> | undefined> | Promise<any[] | Iterable<any> | undefined>'.
  Overload 2 of 3, '(obj: null | undefined): null', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'any[] | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'null | undefined'.
  Overload 3 of 3, '(obj: Observable<any[] | Iterable<any> | undefined> | Subscribable<any[] | Iterable<any> | undefined> | Promise<any[] | Iterable<any> | undefined> | null | undefined): any[] | ... 2 more ... | undefined', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'any[] | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Observable<any[] | Iterable<any> | undefined> | Subscribable<any[] | Iterable<any> | undefined> | Promise<any[] | Iterable<any> | undefined> | null | undefined'.
      Type 'any[]' is not assignable to type 'Observable<any[] | Iterable<any> | undefined> | Subscribable<any[] | Iterable<any> | undefined> | Promise<any[] | Iterable<any> | undefined> | null | undefined'.
        Type 'any[]' is missing the following properties from type 'Observable<any[] | Iterable<any> | undefined>': source, operator, lift, subscribe, and 2 more.

49             <tr *ngFor="let tuto of tutos | async">
                                   ~~~~
```

Answer (score 0):

The angular [async pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe) is meant to be used with [Observable](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/class/Observable) variables, your "tuto" variable is not an observable, that is the reason for the error.

The best option to fix it is to make it an observable (without subscribing):

```
this.tuto$ = this.menuService.getAll().snapshotChanges().pipe(
      map(changes =>
        changes.map(c =>
          ({ key: c.payload.key, ...c.payload.val() })
        )
      )
    );
```

Then on the template (the async pipe will do the subscription for you):

```
<tr *ngFor="let tuto of tutos$ | async">
```

now as to why the data is not showing:

- first look at your browser's network tab and verify that there is data being retrieved when you call `this.menuService.getAll().snapshotChanges()`
- add a `console.log` into your `map(changes =>` call to see that this mapping is doing the right thing

That should get you unstuck.